# Combining and replicating cells in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, replication

I have a file which has 4 tabs in it each for a different user.
       Users enter details of clients handled by them on a daily basis in the tab corresponding to their name.
       I want the last tab to be the collection of all the data which has been entered by all the users in their respective tabs. The data should not overlap and I should be able to filter it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tiny macro:

```
Sub GatherData()
    Dim s As Worksheet, nLastRow As Long, sm As Worksheet
    Set sm = Sheets("Master")

    For Each s In Sheets
        If s.Name <> "Master" Then
            Set r = sm.UsedRange
            nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row
            s.UsedRange.Copy sm.Cells(nLastRow, 1)
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a number of functions across tabs, for example with the **SUM** formula:

`=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)`

will give you the sum of values in the cell **A1** in tabs **Sheet1** to **Sheet3**

Hope that helps